# Magento CE 2.2.2 Elastic Search No Products Front End Category / Listing Pages

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, apache, elasticsearch

Magento CE 2.2.2 
ElasticSearch 6.4
PHP 7.1
Apache 2.4

Magento CE 2.2.2 Elastic Search No Products Front End Category / Listing Pages

We have installed

Amasty Layered Navigation
Amasty ElasticSearch

When we enable in admin Amasty Elasticsearch - changed it from Mysql to Amasty Elasticsearch - our products on the front end - category/listing pages disappear -

Magento admin -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search

If I then RESAVE in admin same product they appear in the front end.

I spent a long time researching and notice other people with similar issues when enabling ElasticSearch but no fixes. This is the same problem with other company elastic search extension.

Comment: Also looking for a fix on this.